# i want to fetch facebook wall messages through c#

Tags: c#, facebook

I’m able to post on wall, but I need to fetch Facebook wall messages through C#

==**Update**==

Now I’m getting wall messages, but now I want the messages with date.

Comment: What code do you have? What doesn't work? We don't do "give me the code" here, but help out with what you do have.

Answer (score 1):

[Facebook developer kit](http://facebooktoolkit.codeplex.com/) is your way to go...

Answer (score 1):

You need the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api).

And to make a request to get the wall posts you need a [extended permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) on the authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Have you studied the FB API already or are you starting from scratch?

You can use Stream.Get to access wall posts, try reading the wiki:

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Stream.get

(You must have permission to access the users page of course)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many ways to do this, here is one example:

Make sure you have the permission "read_stream".
Then read all streams to get the messages on the wall;

```
  var streams = API.Stream.Get(new List<long> { }, null, null, null);
  streams.posts.stream_post.ForEach(post => Console.WriteLine(post.message));
```

'API' comes from your masterpage that has been inherited by Facebook.Web.CanvasIFrameMasterPage.

Comment: hi
thanks for reply
but it gives news feed and i want to fetch wall message.

Answer (score 0):

Responding to an old question, but i recently wrote a blog post on the same, i think it might help others who land to this question while Google search, read the post here (its using a custom built Facebook Connector)

[click here to read](http://blog.impact-works.com/2011/07/06/reading-facebook-users-wall-with-asp-net-c-using-facebook-graph-api-part-3/)

Answer (score 0):

I want to do the same. Facebook API is changing and now it only returns few of the post even if you put LIMIT and UNTIL/SINCE parameters, so you have to change to FQL.
With FQL you can read stream table and get the posts made by the user and the post made by others in the walls's user.